# How to find the ith number that has n factors, considering that n isn't prime?

Tags: numbers, factors, prime-factoring, computer-science-theory, factoring

The brute force approach would be checking every possible number.
If it has **n** factors: **x**++.

until: **x** = i.

but I just learned that you could get **i** = 1 that has **n** factors by:

1. Getting the set **S** of prime factors **e** of n.
2. Arrange set **S** in descending order.
3. Subtract 1 from every element **e** of set **S**.
4. Put a prime number **p** as base, such that:
   **p**<sub>x-1</sub>< **p**<sub>x</sub>, and treat **e**<sub>x</sub> as exponent, for each element of set **S**.
5. Multiply every element.

Now given **i** = 1, What is the possible approach to get the **i**th term?


If you could provide an answer that would work on prime numbers that would be great.